# How do I get PUG to display a dataset the way I want?

Tags: node.js, dataset, pug

I am able to query and get data from SQL Server using tedious. I am having trouble displaying it using PUG:

extends layout

```
block content
  h1= title
  p Welcomes dbe to #{title}

  h1 SQL Results are as follows:
  ul
   each item, i in dataset
     li= JSON.stringify(item)
```

This is what shows in the browser
{"col":"people_id","val":"07BD9B88-CAC2-4351-9FA7-B99F8949F7CE"}
{"col":"client","val":"Bourne, Jason."}

What I would like is 
client: Bourne, Jason

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. Called res.render from  Tedious request.on('doneProc', function (rowCount, more, returnStatus, rows) and populated the dataset in the request.on('row', function (columns) {

Comment: Please post the solution as an answer to your question, or remove the question.

Answer (score 0):

I have not really solved my problem. I was able to have the display as I want it. First I changed the population of the data to 
    if(column.metadata.colName==="client") {
     dataset.push(column.value);
    }

My pug code is now
   table
    thead
      tr
        th Clients
    tbody
      - each item in dataset
        tr
          td= item

This is not exactly as I want but it did solve the question as posed. I am feeling my way around this

In above code snippet dataset is an array. I changed it to an array of objects and now PUG is working as I want.